# Регулярка для url

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая регулярка

```
$s = preg_replace('/some\/([^a-z])\/([^0-9])/','some/$1/$2', $this->entered_uri);
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы url не мог принимать третий, четвертый и т.п. параметр ? Т.е. только `some/$1/$2` и ничего более. Например, если я ввожу в адр. строку:

`some/test/test1/test2/test3` - то это и показывает, а нужно только `some/test/test1`. Остальное отсечь, либо вывести ошибку

Comment: а при чем тут замена? если хотите отсечь остальное, то сделайте preg_match ограничив конец выражения с `$`, а противном случаее отправляйте 404 или чего там

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
/some\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+).*/
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/raD2pK/1/).

**Подробности**

- `some\/` - строка `some/`
- `([^\/]+)` - Подмаска №1 (`$1`): один и более символов, отличных от `\/`
- `\/` - символ `\/`
- `([^\/]+)` - Подмаска №2 (`$2`): один и более символов, отличных от `\/`
- `.*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от символов переноса строки, как можно больше (т.е. оставшаяся часть строки).

Если нужно удалить все нецифровые символы в тексте, захваченным первой подмаской, можно воспользоваться `preg_replace_callback`:

```php
$this_entered_uri = "some/ads123/test1";
echo preg_replace_callback('/some\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+).*/', function($x) {
    return 'some/' . preg_replace('~\D+~', '', $x[1]) . '/' . $x[2];
}, $this_entered_uri);
```

См. [пример работы кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/cHHeO).

Comment: Если мне для первой маски, например, нужно удалять все, кроме \d, как видоизменить данную конструкцию ? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @sousage1212 Регулярные выражения не удаляют ничего, лишь находят нужный текст. Поясните, что вам нужно.

Comment: Если url имеет вид some/ads123/test1, то в первом параметре оставить только 123. Т.е. - some/123/test1

Comment: В принципе не важно.. отдельной регуляркой обработаю..через пару минут выберу ответом т.к. блок. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @sousage1212 Сейчас напишу. Написал.